# Stacked Bar Graph Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, stackedbarseries

Say I have data as follows:

```
 level,age
     8,10
     8,11
     8,11
     9,10
     9,11
     9,11
     9,11
```

I'm looking to form a stacked bar graph in Matlab where "level" is on the x-axis and number of occurances of that level (the frequency) is on the y-axis: so 8 would have a y-value of 3 and 9 would have a y-value of 4. Furthermore, I'm looking to have this as a stacked bar chart so level 8 would have 1 unit colored green (green is age 10) and 2 units colored red (where red is age 11) and 9 would have 1 unit colored green and 3 units colored red.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in a fairly compact and general way using the function [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html) like so, where `data` is your 7-by-2 sample matrix of data:

```
ageValues = unique(data(:,2));          %# Vector of unique age values
barData = accumarray(data(:,1),data(:,2),[],@(x) {hist(x,ageValues)});
X = find(~cellfun('isempty',barData));  %# Find x values for bars
Y = vertcat(barData{:});                %# Matrix of y values for bars
hBar = bar(X,Y,'stacked');              %# Create a stacked histogram
set(hBar,{'FaceColor'},{'g';'r'});      %# Set bar colors
legend(cellstr(num2str(ageValues)),'Location','NorthWest');  %# Add a legend
```

Note that the cell array of colors `{'g';'r'}` passed to the function [SET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/set.html) in the second-to-last line should have the same number of elements as `ageValues` to function properly.

And here's the resulting [bar graph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar.html):

[image]

Comment: +1 nice use of ACCUMARRAY. I would make the code more general by not hard-coding the values `[10 11]` in the HISTC call, instead using `uniqAge=unique(data(:,2));`. Also the legend is somewhat needed here: `legend( strtrim(cellstr(num2str(uniqAge,'Age %d'))), 'Location','NorthWest')`

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want using the [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) and [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html) functions to get the unique values and frequency counts and then use the `'stacked'` option in [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar.html) to plot the data. Note that in the following, I have taken `level` and `age` to be column vectors. I've also made the central parts of the code general instead of for this specific example.

```
level=[8,8,8,9,9,9,9]';              %'#SO code formatting
age=[10,11,11,10,11,11,11]';         %'

%#get unique values and frequency count
uniqLevel=unique(level);
freqLevel=histc(level,uniqLevel);    
uniqAge=unique(age);

%#combine data in a manner suitable for bar(...,'stacked')
barMatrix=cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)histc(age(level==uniqLevel(x)),uniqAge),...
    1:numel(uniqLevel),'UniformOutput',false));

%#plot the stacked bars and customize
hb=bar(barMatrix','stacked');        %'

set(gca,'xticklabel',uniqLevel,'ytick',1:max(sum(barMatrix)))
set(hb(uniqAge==10),'facecolor','green')
set(hb(uniqAge==11),'facecolor','red')

xlabel('Level')
ylabel('Occurrence')
legend('10','11','location','northwest')
```

[image]